# how to skip search the system table when using the eclipselink timestamp optimistic clock

Tags: java, locking, db2, eclipselink

When I try to using eclipselink to implement the concurrent event in the DB2.I added an annotation @Version in the entity class:

```
@Version
    @Column(name = "LAST_MNT_TS")
    private Timestamp lastMaintenanceTimestamp;
```

After that I try to update the table, it seems like will calling the system table to search the timestamp. But, I do not have the permission for the DB2 system table .And the exception is:

```
[EL Fine]: 2011-06-28 11:05:21.98--ClientSession(15607581)--Connection(11405376)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT DISTINCT CURRENT TIMESTAMP FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
[EL Fine]: 2011-06-28 11:05:22.309--ClientSession(15607581)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--VALUES(1)
[EL Warning]: 2011-06-28 11:05:22.637--UnitOfWork(19624355)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -551, SQLSTATE: 42501, SQLERRMC: DT82056;SELECT;SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
Error Code: -551
Call: SELECT DISTINCT CURRENT TIMESTAMP FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="SELECT DISTINCT CURRENT TIMESTAMP FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES")
[EL Config]: 2011-06-28 11:05:29.715--ServerSession(16239564)--Connection(11405376)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--disconnect
```

How can I skip the search in the system table?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I saw in the EclipseLink code, you may need to open a bug for this issue. I don't use EclipseLink, but I took a minute to download the latest release of the source to see if the problem was still there.

The source for org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DB2Platform shows that getTimestampQuery() still returns the same sloppy, wasteful query you're encountering. There is no reason at all to query SYSIBM.SYSTABLES just to get DB2 to hand you a timestamp. If you care enough about this to open a bug, you could recommend that they replace the query with `"SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1"`

Although SYSIBM.SYSTABLES is also referenced by getNativeTableInfo() in the same class, the comments hint that the method is just a compatibility hedge against mediocre JDBC drivers, assuming the method is even called at all.